# unable to or two regex expression for grep

Tags: regex, bash, shell

I want to write a bash script that finds files according to the date they've been modified. for example, this `./find_by_date Jul` should output all files that are modified in **Jul** and this `./find_by_date 8` should output all files that are modified on the **8**th day of a month. and `find_by_date Jul 8` should find all files that are modified on **July 8**.

this is what I have tried so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

function find_by_date
{
    date=$1;
    date=${date:?'missing'};
    echo $(ls -l | grep -i "(.\{37\}$date|.\{40\}$date)" | cut -c51-);
}

find_by_date $1
```

however, the regex for grep does not work properly. if I only use `.\{37\}$date` or `.\{40\}$date`, it works. but if I `or` them, it doesn't work.

can anyone help me with the regex?

**UPDATE 1**

as suggested, I changed the regex to:

```
grep -i -E ".\{37\}$date|.\{40\}$date"
```

still doesn't work.

**UPDATE 2**

this is the directory that I'm running the test on:

```
-rw-r--r-- 1 fatemeh fatemeh     231 Jul  8 19:48 albums.txt
-rw-r--r-- 1 fatemeh fatemeh      47 Jul  8 19:43 alice
-rw-r--r-- 1 fatemeh fatemeh 2540187 Aug  8 00:26 output.txt
-rwxrwxr-x 1 fatemeh fatemeh     178 Aug  8 23:55 p102_ex.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 fatemeh fatemeh     349 Aug  4 20:53 p92_ex.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 fatemeh fatemeh     330 Jul  7 23:55 p97_ex.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 fatemeh fatemeh      98 Aug  8 00:33 p98_ex.sh
-rwxrwxr-x 1 fatemeh fatemeh     255 Aug  9 00:35 stack.sh
-rw-rw-r-- 1 fatemeh fatemeh     720 Aug  8 00:05 test.py
-rwx-wx--x 1 fatemeh fatemeh     207 Aug  1 11:58 test.sh
-rw-r--r-- 1 fatemeh fatemeh       0 Aug  7 00:24 tmp.txt
```

the output of `./find_by_date Jul` must be: `albums.txt alice p97_ex.sh` (all modified in July)

the output of `./find_by_date 7` must be: `p97_ex.sh tmp.txt`

the output of `./find_by_date Aug 8` must be: `output.txt p102_ex.sh p98_ex.sh test.py`

Comment: Supply `-E` flag to grep or backslash every `|`. It should work fine after that.

Comment: @Mihir I did, but it didn't

Comment: edit you Q to include 2 statements to help us test your problem. They should be 2 output records from `ls -l` where one record has a matching date, and the other should not match. Ideally, the will be like `{ echo ".... ls ouput1" ; echo "ls .... output2"; }`. Then we can copy paste good testing data. Good luck.

Comment: @shellter I added some data. hope it helps

Comment: you can do `date=${1:?missing}` instead. AND no need for `echo $(` and the closing `)`. Just `ls -l | ....` Good luck.

Comment: I make your second column at position 42. In any case, I would focus on 1 position, experiement with 39 thru 44 when you get output, then you can get fancy ;-). Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

You have to be aware that parsing the output of `ls` and other utilities should be avoided, because subtle changes of format in UNIX flavors and even among versions render the shell functions unusable.

In any case, for your program, you can write `\|` instead of just the `|` in the regex.

Comment: I added the -E option. but it didn't work. then I added \ for |. didn't work either

Comment: Please use **stat -c '%z' FILE** instead of parsing ls

Answer (score 0):

When you use `grep` without `-E`, it uses POSIX "basic" regular expression syntax. In this syntax, parentheses, curly brackets, bar (alternation), plus, and question mark are all plain characters with no special meaning. Curly brackets (and sometimes some/all of the others) can be given their usual regex meaning by escaping them. If your version of `grep` supports escaped bar parentheses, you could use:

```
grep -i "\(.\{37\}$date\|.\{40\}$date\)"
```

(Note that the parentheses and bar are escaped.) But it's better to use `grep -E`, which invokes "extended" regular expression syntax, in which those characters have their special meanings *unless* they are escaped. This version would be:

```
grep -Ei "(.{37}$date|.{40}$date)"
```

(Note that here the curly braces have had their escapes removed.)

But there are a few other problems here. For one thing, the regex isn't anchored at all, so the first branch will match any occurrence of `$date` *at least* 37 characters into the string (because the 37 characters don't have to start at the beginning of the line). If you want it to match *exactly* 37 characters in, add `^` to the front of the expression to anchor it to the front of the line.

Second, your script only looks at its first argument (`$1`), so `find_by_date Jul 8` will completely ignore the "8". You could merge all arguments with "$*", but that just separates the arguments with a space, and `ls` normally prints e.g. July 8 with two spaces between them. You'd have to use something like this to build a pattern:

```
function find_by_date
{
    datepattern=$1
    shift
    for arg in "$@"; do
        datepattern+=" +$arg"    # " +" will match one or more spaces
    done
...
find_by_date "$@"    # "$@" will pass on *all* arguments
```

But most importantly `ls` just isn't all that consistent in its output format. The column widths can vary depending on the contents of the fields, so looking for the date in a particular column (and expecting the filename to start at column 51) is chancy at best. You'd be better off using something like `stat`, where you can control the output format.

(Unfortunately, that last point makes the others mostly moot. You really need to change the overall approach.)